# Best Build Workflow for Node and Docker

Tags: docker, workflow, devops

For node applications, what is the better option for building lightweight images?

1. **Single Docker Image.** Might require build tools and would expose all build time environment variables to the container.

   ```
   yarn install # install deps and devDeps
   yarn build # build our application
   yarn test # perform tests
   yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline # Remove devDeps
   rm -rf src # Remove source files
   yarn start
   ```
2. **Multiple Docker Images**

   In one docker container that has build tools, do the:

   ```
   yarn install
   yarn build
   yarn test
   ```

   Then take the build assets and `package.json`, and copy them into a new container which would have only runtime environment variables. The result is a much smaller image (perhaps `node:alpine`) that has only very limited source files.

   ```
   yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline
   yarn start
   ```

Comment: If you're aiming for lightweight images, why do you think the first one could ever be better?

Comment: I think the second option is better @jonrsharpe for lightweight images as they contain only what is neccessary to run despite the more complicated setup process.  But I see so many projects use option 1, and I wonder if there is something I am missing.

Comment: So did you try either of them? What happened? Maybe other projects aren't aware of the options, or have different goals to yours?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build lightweight image for your application, keep in mind the following:

1. Try to use alpine images, e.g. [node:8.12.0-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) as alpine images are lightest base os image. If you want to install packages, do `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual your_packages... && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*`
2. Try to reduce number of layers by running multiple commands in same `RUN` statement, e.g. `RUN yarn install && yarn build && yarn test && yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline && rm
   -rf src && yarn start`
3. Try to club commands that cancel out each other, e.g. `RUN apk update && apk add ... && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*`. Here `apk update` creates a cache and `rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*` clears it. No need to run these two commands separately as they are cancelling out each others work hence no point in having two layers which negate each other and inflate the size of the final image.

**Note**: Having multiple docker files instead of one is not going to reduce the number of layers or shrink the size. It only gives you logical separation of tasks that you want to handle individually.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I guess it is not practical to to run the build + testing + cleanup commands  as a single RUN statement to avoid the extra layer, but more 'cleaner' to run them separately but ultimatly copy them to the final container resulting in just one layer.